# "Provided module can't be loaded" error when trying to load GoogleCloud Datastore module with Nodejs 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

As part of the implementation of a Cloud Function under Google Cloud Platform, executed with Nodejs 8, I have to store information in GCP Datastore.

I use TypeScript which is compiled in Javascript.

I have the following error when I try to import the `"@google-cloud/datastore"` module:

> Provided module can't be loaded.
>  Is there a syntax error in your
>   code?
>  Detailed stack trace: **TypeError: extend must be a string**

I tried 2 ways to import the module and each time I get the same error:

```js
import {Datastore} from '@google-cloud/datastore';
const datastore = new Datastore();
```

or

```js
const datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
```

I also tried to install different versions of the module, nothing helps.

Finally, I realized that even when the module is not installed (I executed the command `npm uninstall @google-cloud/datastore`), I get the exact same error when logically, when we try to import a module which is not installed, we should have the following error:

> Provided module can't be loaded.
>  Did you list all required modules
>   in the package.json dependencies?
>  Detailed stack trace: **Error:
>   Cannot find module 'test'**

Has anyone ever encountered this problem or would have a clue why I get this error?

Comment: see this https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore#using-the-client-library maybe it will help

Comment: did you added the module into the dependencies in your package.json? if not add it `"@google-cloud/datastore": "^5.0.3"`

Comment: I did add the module in the dependencies in my package.json.
I also did look at the documentation but found nothing helpful.

There appears to be a conflict between Datastore and QuickBase.
In my index file, I have other GCP functions that use QuickBase. When I comment all calls to QuickBase, my function using Datastore compiles without error.

Has anyone ever encountered this conflict and might know how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue while deploying the functions, later I realized that I installed the packages in wrong location.

My folder structure was this:

- /

  - functions

    - node_modules
    - index.js
      ...

By mistake I installed all the packages at / level:

- /

  - functions

    - node_modules
    - index.js
      ...
  - node_modules

So all my packages were in the outer node_modules.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, How can I change the wrong package location?

Comment: @MarkChoi Change your directory; `cd ./functions/` and then run the `npm install <module>` command.

Comment: I did the same thing, and the solution helped me to solve this problem. But what files can be deleted due to they are in the wrong place?

Comment: @HogRider you can delete the entire `node_modules` folder present in the wrong location this is only if you have done `npm install` in the wrong location.